# Calculate a position of a point in 3D space knowing locations of 3 other points and distances beetwen them and the 1st point in lua

Tags: lua

I am looking for a way to calculate a position of any point in 3D space (X, Y, Z where X is width, Y is height and Z is depth) based on the knowledge of location of 3 or more other points and their distance to the point I want to know the position of. Example data:

X: 414, Y: 71, Z: -963, Distance: 87 (rounded down)
X: 612, Y: 72, Z: -935, Distance: 120 (rounded up)
X: 500, Y: 66, Z: -974, Distance: 2 (rounded down)

I already tried porting the following javascript library: [trilateration.js](https://github.com/gheja/trilateration.js/blob/master/trilateration.js#) as it was suggested by other SO answers looking for a simmilar thing but the results generated by that port of library are highly inaccurate no matter what sort of sorting tricks I do.

Sidenote: I usually have more than 3 points, perhaps I could sort them based on the distance and use those with shortest distance, that would increase the accuracy.

My programming environment for lua (minecraft OpenComputers) doesn't allow C code loading so any solutions using native libraries are out of the question.

Comment: How could you ask for an accurate solution while your input data is "rounded down" (not exact)?

Comment: Right, I will update the question with non-rounded data (keep in mind the positions are integers)

Comment: There would be 2 solutions (mirrored over the 3-point plane).  Probably, more than 3 point are needed.